# Mutating and non-mutating method chains

Tags: rust

I have two functions, which I'm hoping to use in method chains. They both do basically the same thing, except that one of them overwrites itself and another returns a clone. I'm coming from Ruby, and I'm used to just calling `self.dup.mutable_method` in the destructive method.

I believe I have a solution worked out in Rust, but I'm not sure whether it has an extra allocation going on in there somewhere, and I'm afraid that it'll consume itself. This is audio DSP code, so I want to make sure that there are no allocations in the mutable method. (I'm three days into Rust, so mea culpa for the non-generalized trait impls.)

```
impl Filter for DVec<f64> {
    fn preemphasis_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, freq: f64, sample_rate: f64) -> &'a mut DVec<f64> {
        let filter = (-2.0 * PI * freq / sample_rate).exp();
        for i in (1..self.len()).rev() {
            self[i] -= self[i-1] * filter;
        };
        self
    }

    fn preemphasis(&self, freq: f64, sample_rate: f64) -> DVec<f64> {
        let mut new = self.clone();
        new.preemphasis_mut(freq, sample_rate);
        new
    }
}


// Ideal code:
let mut sample: DVec<f64> = method_that_loads_sample();
let copy_of_sample = sample.preemphasis(75.0, 44100.0); // this mutates and copies, with one allocation
sample.preemphasis_mut(75.0, 44100.0); // this mutates in-place, with no allocations
copy_of_sample.preemphasis_mut(75.0, 44100.0)
    .preemphasis_mut(150.0, 44100.0); // this mutates twice in a row, with no allocations
```

Comment: This looks more like a code review than a question. (1) I suppose the question is "Is there any allocation in `preemphasis_mut`?" and (2) can only wonder at what you mean by "consume itself"?

Comment: I agree that this could also be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but make sure you read [the guidelines for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) as the rules there are slightly different. Namely, you should have the whole program, not just snippets.

Comment: "consumed" was not quite the right word—should have really been "moved." But I see now (in the morning) that passing a borrowed reference as `&self` to the function ensures that it won't be moved.

Comment: I just ran into this problem writing a lexer with `peek_token` and `next_token` methods. I'm stumped for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen any libraries follow any patterns similar to Ruby's `foo` and `foo!` method pairs when it comes to self mutation. I believe this mostly to be because Rust places mutability front-and-center, so it's much more difficult to "accidentally" mutate something. To that end, I would probably drop one of your methods and allow the user to decide when something should be mutated:

```
use std::f64::consts::PI;

trait Filter {
    fn preemphasis<'a>(&'a mut self, freq: f64, sample_rate: f64) -> &'a mut Self;
}

impl Filter for Vec<f64> {
    fn preemphasis<'a>(&'a mut self, freq: f64, sample_rate: f64) -> &'a mut Self {
        let filter = (-2.0 * PI * freq / sample_rate).exp();
        for i in (1..self.len()).rev() {
            self[i] -= self[i-1] * filter;
        };
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut sample = vec![1.0, 2.0];
    // this copies then mutates, with one allocation
    let mut copy_of_sample = sample.clone();
    copy_of_sample
        .preemphasis(75.0, 44100.0); 
    // this mutates in-place, with no allocations
    sample
        .preemphasis(75.0, 44100.0); 
    // this mutates twice in a row, with no allocations
    copy_of_sample
        .preemphasis(75.0, 44100.0)
        .preemphasis(150.0, 44100.0);
}
```

I think a key thing here is that the *caller* of the code can easily see when something will be mutated (because of the `&mut` reference to `self`). The *caller* also gets to determine when and where the `clone` happens.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. (And I realized that I don't really want "_mut" sprinkled over all my method calls anyway.)

Comment: @acsmith to be fair, there *are* method pairs that are `foo` and `foo_mut`, but those usually give different views *into* an object, not change how the method works. `iter` and `iter_mut` are prime examples.

Comment: yes, that's the model I was looking at initially, but I see the difference between this and Ruby's ! now. Thanks.